# Does a child own what he's implicitly given by his parents?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, children-parenting, transactions, family-members

I assume that when a parent owns an object and a child uses it, it remains the property of the parent's absent any intent/declaration on the parent's part to grant it to the child (and absent an act of *kinyan*, acquisition). Thus, for example, if a parent buys a piece of furniture and puts it in the child's room in the parent's house, whether that child is a *bar mitzva* or not yet, but assuming the child is dependent on the parent, then the furniture remains the parent's. (If that's wrong, please source a correction, and that'd make a good answer.)

My questions are:

- Do any sources discuss whether referring to the object as the child's constitutes a declaration of intent to grant it to the child? For example, if the parent says "this X is yours" or "this X is for you" or "your X is dirty", do any sources say that constitutes sufficient declaration of intent to grant the X to the child, so that the child need then only drag or lift the X (*SA CM* 200:2) in order to acquire it?

If *not* — if, in fact, the object remains the parent's property —

Or, in a case in which such acquisition has not occurred, and the object is, so far, the parent's property —

- Is there any extent to which a parent-owned object assigned to the use of a specific child (again, whether a minor or a *bar mitzva* but assuming the child is dependent on and living with the parent) is considered that child's? That is, is there any *halacha* such that the object, although technically owned by the parents, is considered the child's for the purposes of that *halacha*?

Comment: Some potential relevant areas include lulav and tzedaka.

Comment: The first days of Sukkot, you're supposed to give your lulav to someone else as a present, with the condition that he returns it to you afterwards. The books say not to do this to a child, because a child can acquire something, but can't give it to away to someone else. Since the lulav is supposed to be yours (at least the first 2 day in diaspora), this would prevent you from doing the mitzvah or letting anyone else do so. Following this train of thought would probably shed light on the issue. http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/dafyomi2/sukah/insites/su-dt-46.htm - Sukkah 46B

Comment: @Menachem Note though that the question asked about children over 13 as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Menachem, yes. One application I was thinking of for my second bullet point is: Something is considered a _basis_ for _muktze_ only if _muktze_ was placed there by the owner of the potential _basis_. (Usually.) What if a 13-year-old placed _muktze_ on "his" bed? **But** I didn't include it in the question as I didn't want its details to be addressed in an answer, preferring to stick to generalities.

Comment: Can we clarify the question as to whether we are talking about a katan or not? If we aren't talking about ketanim can you clarify why the parent child relationship would be different than any other relationships vis-a-vis kinyanim?

Comment: @AdamSimon, I took pains to clarify as much as I reasonably could that I'm asking about both a minor and a child who has reached majority. A parent-child relationship can differ from others when the child is dependent on the parent. That comes up in various halachic discussions. I'll edit the question to clarify that I'm asking about such a child; thanks for making me clarify.

Comment: @AdamSimon "whether that child is a bar mitzva or not yet" was in the first edition of this question, and has remained in it since.

Comment: Without wanting to spoil the chances of others, of getting the rich bounty. The answer can be found by looking at, if a man went bankrupt and had to pay all his property to his creditors, do they also get his childrens property.

Comment: @shulem If they got his children's property, it might be because he has some sort of lien on it, not because it wasn't theirs.

Comment: @Double AA, Metaltelin are not usually meshubad to a baal chov. Only karkar is. A person can give away all he has got, and the creditor cant do anything about it. So if he gives his children and its considered theirs they cant take it. I think thats right.

Comment: By Mitzvois that have to be YOURS in order to fulfil the Mitzvah (like Tzitzis and Lulav) we say that if one gives it to his friend to use -even if he didn't say 'on condition that you give it back'- that Leiv Bais Din that he transferred it him in a way that it would be YOURS during the Mitzvah. This would imply that other things (that are not Mitzvos) it does not become YOURS (or the child's in the question) without proper intent and Kinyan. Even for a Ganov to acquire the Genaivah he has to make a Kinyan. In the extreme the child would be a Nifkad and that also needs a Kinyan.

Comment: @shulem Metaltelin are not usually meshubad to a baal chov, and this is not a usual case of a baal chov.

Comment: why not? Isnt that what this case is. Does it belong to the child or not.

Comment: Of possible interest: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98146/170

Comment: possibly related: _Arachin_ 6.5

Answer (score 2):

There is an extent to which a parent-owned object assigned to the use of a specific child is his, we give our children (and guests) Matzo on Pesach night which must belong to you [see](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/454/9.htm) SA Horav OC Siman 454:9 and [here](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_5/0098_Siman_454_Seif_3b-4a.pdf) then [here](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_5/0099_Siman_454_Seif_4b-Siman_455_Seif_1a.pdf) in Mishnah Berurah 454:15 -even if they don't make a Kinyan (let's say we put it in their mouth)- they fulfilled their obligation.

Rambam in Hilchos Korban Pesach 5:7 writes that a Koton who became Bar Mitzvah between Pesach Rishon and Pesach Sheni has to bring a Korban Pesach on Pesach Sheni; but if they slaughtered the Korban Pesach (in Nissan) with the child in mind then he's exempt from Pesach Sheni. We see here that even though the child didn't make a Kinyan (there is no such requirement) he still had a Zechus in it.

See also Rambam Hilchos Michusrei Kaporo 3:6 and Hilchos Isurei Bi'ah 3:17 about children bringing Korbonos.

Comment: If the matza trick works for guests too, then that seems to be more of a din in feeding guests than in a parent-child relationship.

Comment: A possible citation (which I haven't checked) relevant to this answer: _Rama EH_ 28:17 with _nos'e kelim_ and _Chochmas Sh'lomo_. Ping @DoubleAA too.