# Is using a parent's hidden object stealing?

Tags: gezel-stealing

Let’s say a mom has food hidden in her makeup kit in her bedroom and her son finds it and eats it.  I’ve heard somewhere that kids are allowed to use various things in the home of their parents. So, if the mom didn’t directly say “don’t eat this food”, would sources consider this stealing? Also would the son allowed to share the food with his friends, or would this be stealing?

Comment: Like all people they can use anything the owner of that thing allows them to use. For most children I'd guess that's most things at home.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think that's so obvious, here. My wife frequently hides food in a closet so that my kids or I can't get to it. Thus, the specific reason as to why it is hidden is that it should **not** be eaten. Thus, eating it may not specifically be "stealing" but in the case of a child doing it, there may be other halachic violations.

Comment: @DanF If your wife owns it and doesn't let you use it then using it is theft.

Comment: Of possible interest: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17805/170